# ASP.NET javascript. Put it in code behind or put it in .aspx file?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Why do people put javascript in the code behind ?  I think it is ugly to have 100 (see below) of these.... Is there some basic reasons that javascript must be in the code behind in some instances? And when it should in the aspx. ??

```
 // now we gotta recalc fields                 
            szCalcBenefitsTotal += "         CalcCostFromPct('" + tbSocialSecurityPercent3.ClientID + "', '" + tbSocialSecurity3.ClientID + "', '" + tbSalaryAdjusted3.ClientID + "');";
            szCalcBenefitsTotal += "         CalcCostFromPct('" + tbMedicarePercent3.ClientID + "', '" + tbMedicare3.ClientID + "', '" + tbSalaryAdjusted3.ClientID + "');";
            szCalcBenefitsTotal += "         CalcCostFromPct('" + tbHealthInsurancePercent3.ClientID + "', '" + tbHealthInsurance3.ClientID + "', '" + tbSalaryAdjusted3.ClientID + "');";
            szCalcBenefitsTotal += "         CalcCostFromPct('" + tbLifeInsurancePercent3.ClientID + "', '" + tbLifeInsurance3.ClientID + "', '" + tbSalaryAdjusted3.ClientID + "');";
            szCalcBenefitsTotal += "         CalcCostFromPct('" + tbVacationPercent3.ClientID + "', '" + tbVacation3.ClientID + "', '" + tbSalaryAdjusted3.ClientID + "');";
            szCalcBenefitsTotal += "         CalcCostFromPct('" + tbSickLeavePercent3.ClientID + "', '" + tbSickLeave3.ClientID + "', '" + tbSalaryAdjusted3.ClientID + "');";
            szCalcBenefitsTotal += "         CalcCostFromPct('" + tbRetirementPercent3.ClientID + "', '" + tbRetirement3.ClientID + "', '" + tbSalaryAdjusted3.ClientID + "');";
```

Comment: Ok. So I guess it is safe you say you should only put it in your .aspx unless theres a really good reason. 

In this example I have a work I don't see the reason. (Its just grabbing HTML textboxes and doing calculations) ..  The same thing can be done client side with the <%= clientID %> right?

Comment: Updated my answer to answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely in the code-behind because the javascript is dynamically generated by ASP.NET Code. It's not the best way to do it, it's better to inject variables in places and use static jscript to act upon the dynamically generated variables.

I would suggest putting your javascript in it's own .js file not cluttering up your html markup if possible, otherwise put it in the .aspx

**Edit:** *(To answer your comment question)*

Yes, you can do the same thing using `<%= %>` and `<%# %>` and in ASP.NET 4.0 `<%: %>`. Also constructs like `<asp:Repeater></asp:Repeater>` can be used to loop over lists/enumerables, so in theory you can do pretty-much everything in the .aspx

Answer (score 1):

You're  right; it is ugly.

They're probably generating the Javascript based on some information that is only available in the code-behind.

In general, you should put your Javascript in the ASPX, or (preferably) in a separate .JS file.